# Kentico display category ID

Tags: categories, transformation, kentico

Is it possible to display category ID in current product document transformation in Kentico?
Maybe there some simple solution, something like 
    <%# Eval("CategoryID")%> 
?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to create a custom function for the transformation. In EVAL you can use basically the fields that are in the view View_CMS_Tree_Joined. If you are using a category selector for given document type, then you can use the name of this field. If you are using the default categories on Properties tab, these are linked via CMS_DocumentCategory table - so, in your custom transformation function you will need to get the category ID based on the current document ID.